# Arguments for `vpList` from `grid` package

Tags: r

This is probably silly but how do I dynamically create a `vpTree` like

```r
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
vpTree( viewport(layout=grid.layout(2,2), name = "body"), vpList(viewport(name= "a"), viewport(name ="b"), viewport(name = "c"), viewport(name = "d")))
#> viewport[body]->(viewport[a], viewport[b], viewport[c], viewport[d])
```

I cannot pass a list of viewports:

```r
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
n <- c(viewport(name= "a"), viewport(name ="b"), viewport(name = "c"), viewport(name = "d"))
vpTree( viewport(layout=grid.layout(2,2), name = "body"), vpList(n))
#> Error in vpListFromList(vps): only viewports allowed in 'vpList'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing `vpList` does is to convert its argument in a list. I needed to overwrite the `vpList` function from grid with a custom function to bypass the list from

```
> vpList
function (...) 
{
    vps <- list(...)
    vpListFromList(vps)
}
<bytecode: 0x000002e14a815a60>
<environment: namespace:grid>
```

to

```
vpList <- function (vps) 
{
  grid:::vpListFromList(vps)
}
```

Like this:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()

vpListX <- function (vps) 
{
  grid:::vpListFromList(vps)
}


n <- list(viewport(name= "a"), viewport(name ="b"), viewport(name = "c"), viewport(name = "d"))
vpTree( viewport(layout=grid.layout(2,2), name = "body"), vpListX(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you create vpList is incorrect.
Try this-

```
##Supply same list to variable and then pass it in function

library(grid)
grid.newpage()
n <- vpList(viewport(name= "a"), viewport(name ="b"), viewport(name = "c"), viewport(name = "d"))
vpTree( viewport(layout=grid.layout(2,2), name = "body"), n)
```

Comment: This yields a different structure `viewport[body]->(viewport[a]->viewport[b]->viewport[c]->viewport[d]) ` vs `viewport[body]->(viewport[a], viewport[b], viewport[c], viewport[d])` and `vpStack()` does  not support a list of viewports. From my understanding `vpStack` renders sequentially while `vpTree` renders *simulatenously* (whatever that means lol)

Comment: @Jrakru56 Check Edited solution. Is this what you are trying?

Comment: Not quite, I want to create a `viewport` of an arbitrary number of `viewport`s . With this approach, I have to hard code my viewports in advance. `vpList` converts its argument into a list.  I guess I will have to overwrite the function ... somehow.